# display page as Normal(320) size?

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

Is it possible to force an app to display a site in normal resolution instead of large?

I am building an app which contains non-dynamic imagery - so I need to add additional stylesheets for each of the main screen sizes, the test phones I have been working with displayed  the screen as a 320px wide until I upgraded the version of jquery library I had been using and it now displays as a 420px size.

I'm happy to make style sheets for both, but as it looked fine in the first place so I wonder whether it is possible to force the width to stay at 320?  It would just save me a task and make the app lighter.

Any suggestions?

Cheers
Paul

Comment: Have you tried to set `max-width: 320px` on your top level container element?

Comment: just tried it and no luck - cheers for the tip though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are building site for mobile browsers, there is a direct way to list the width for your site, and the phone's browser will resize it accordingly to device specs.

Try

```
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Specific to your case

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320px">
```

Comment: FYI you may want to test this on ICS as I think there is a bug where it does not respect the viewport settings.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be as easy as putting `max-width: 320px` somewhere but if you use your developer tools to inspect the DOM to find-out what styles are being applied you **can** limit the size of your website with `max-width`.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LV9Kv/ (click the content to change it's size with only the `max-width` property)

Comment: cheers for your help jasper, but the viewport content width worked perfectly

Comment: Yeah don't know why I didn't think of that. If you check-out the MDN or Apple docs about the `viewport` tag there are some interesting settings you can set.

Comment: Cheers Jasper I will take a look